# Does $\int\limits^\pi_1\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)}{\sqrt{x} }dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

This is what I have, though I'm most likely missing something:

$$\int\limits^\pi_1\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)}{\sqrt{x} }dx \le \int\limits_1^{\pi}\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)dx\le\int\limits_1^\pi dx=\pi-1$$

Therefore converges.

What about when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \cos x=0$, what to do about this?

Comment: You may want to add absolute values, because comparison only works for positive functions. Otherwise, the function is just not defined at one point, but it does not matter for integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the interval $[1,\pi]$:

$$\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\right|\le\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)\right|\le 1$$

therefore

$$
\int\limits^\pi_1 \left| \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)}{\sqrt{x} }\right|\,dx\le \int\limits^\pi_1 \,dx=\pi - 1$$

so the integral converges.

Comment: The last inequality should be directly with the absolute value *inside* the integral. Otherwise, you are taking the absolute value of something that you do not even know makes sense.